# Renaming files from bash in linux

Tags: bash, files, rename, time, sort

There is a bunch of files of the following format hh-mm-ss.png where hh, mm, ss are hour, minute and second. How can I rename all these files in the directory in a sequential way from 1.png til n.png so that all files sorted by hour, then by minutes, then by seconds. For example,

```
12-56-11.png -> 3.png
11-13-49.png -> 1.png
12-55-55.png -> 2.png
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution using a `for` loop and bash arithmetic:

```
i=1
for file in ??-??-??.png ; do
    mv "$file" $i.png
    let i++
done
```

Comment: ARGHMETICS!! I know, they are frustrating..

Comment: You should note that this only works because bash expands "??-??-??.png" in the order Sergey asked for.  That is, "hh-mm-ss" sorts in lexical order by bash expansion, but that just so happens to correspond to ascending timestamp order.

Comment: Just as a cross-reference: [In Bash, are wildcard expansions guaranteed to be in order?](http://serverfault.com/questions/122737/in-bash-are-wildcard-expansions-guaranteed-to-be-in-order),